# using LayoutClickListener to terminary replace components

Tags: java, vaadin

I have grid layout witch some fields added like that:

```
 private Component userDetailsTab(final User user) {
        final GridLayout details = new GridLayout(2, 1);
        details.setMargin(true);
        details.setSpacing(true);

        details.addComponent(createDetailLabel(Messages.User_Name));
        final Component username = createDetailValue(user.getName());
        details.addComponent(username);

        ...
```

I have also Layout click listener which replace labels on text field, it looks like that:

```
 final TextField tf = new TextField();

        details.addListener(new LayoutClickListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -7374243623325736476L;

            @Override
            public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {

                Component com = event.getChildComponent();
                if (event.getChildComponent() instanceof Label) {
                    Label label = (Label)event.getChildComponent();
                    details.replaceComponent(com, tf);
                    tf.setValue(label.getValue());
                }
            }
        });
```

In future I want to enable click on label, edit it and write changes to database after clicking somewhere else (on different label for example).

Now when I click on 1st label and then on 2nd label, effect is: 1st has value of 2nd and 2nd is text field witch value of 2nd. Why it's going that way? What should i do to after clicking on 1st and then 2nd get 1st label witch value of 1st?

Comment: why do you want to edit label? You can use text field/text area for editing and then use button, on click of which data has to be saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to swap between Labels and TextFields, you can just use a TextField and style it look like a Label when it's not focused.

Comment: I cannot do that, cause some labels should have one row and text field for them has to be much bigger, also I'm not sure it's possible to make to style text field to look like label

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to create click-to-edit labels, it created a ton of extra work for me.  I'd discourage it (and do as Patton suggests in the comments).

However, if you're going to insist on trying to create in-place editing, you will want to do the following:

- Create a new class that extends a layout (e.g. HorizontalLayout), which can swap out a label for a text field
- use LayoutClickListener to removeComponent(myLabel) and addComponent(myTextField)
- use BlurListener to swap back to the label
- use ValueChangeListener on the text field to copy its value to the label

This is a still a bad idea because:

- Users cannot see affordances as easily (they can't tell what's editable)
- Users cannot use the keyboard to tab to the field they want to edit
- It adds unncessary complexity (maintenance time, etc).

I would recommend, if you want in-place editing, just show the text field, and save the new value with the BlurListener.